# Php ajax POST metodo

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

lo tengo una duda respecto a un CRUD en php trabajando de forma Asíncrona y quiero saber como seria la inserción de datos, como traerme los datos para la inserción.
Ese es el formulario:

```
            $('#btnGuardar').click(function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                
                var centro={
                    'name':$('#nombreCentro').val(),
                    'calle':$('#calle').val(),
                    'numExt':$('#numExt').val(),
                    'numInt':$('#numInt').val(),
                    'estado':$('#estado').val(),
                    'municipio':$('#municipio').val(),
                    'localidad':$('#localidad').val(),
                    'cp':$('#cp').val(),
                    'pais':'México'
                };
                
                $.post('GuardarCentros.php',{centro:centro},function(resp){
                    
                });
                
            });
            $('form').on('submit',function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                
            });
        });
```

y este es el archivo llamado GuardarCentros.php:

```
    <?php
include './conexion.php';
include './form.php';
foreach (centro as $row){
$name=$row->name;
  $calle=$row->calle;
  $numExt=$row->numExt;
  $numInt=$row->numInt;
  $estado=$row->estado;
  $municipio=$row->municipio;
  $localidad=$row->localidad;
  $cp=$row->cp;
  $pais='México';

  $sql = "INSERT INTO centros(nombre,calle,numext,numint,cp,colonia,municipio,estado,pais) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $calle . "','" . $numExt . "','" . $numInt . "','" . $cp . "','" . $localidad . "','" . $municipio . "','" . $estado . "','" . $pais . "')";
    
  $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($query){
  echo "correcto";
}else{
  echo "incorrecto";
}
}
?>
```

Existe alguna forma de llevarme ese objeto llamado centro al archivo donde hago el insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es enviar un array al servidor, la mejor forma sería la siguiente:

JS:

```
var centro={
                    'name':$('#nombreCentro').val(),
                    'calle':$('#calle').val(),
                    'numExt':$('#numExt').val(),
                    'numInt':$('#numInt').val(),
                    'estado':$('#estado').val(),
                    'municipio':$('#municipio').val(),
                    'localidad':$('#localidad').val(),
                    'cp':$('#cp').val(),
                    'pais':'México'
                };


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {centro:centro},
   url: "GuardarCentros.php",
   success: function(msg){     
   }
});
```

PHP: Recoges el array de la siguiente manera y lo imprimes:

```
$centro= $_POST['centro'];

print_r($centro);
```

Ya con el haces la consulta o lo que consideres.

Un saludo!

Comment: muchas gracias hermano, me ayudaste un montón